# Why would one define a local function in C# just to call it right away (in context of IEnumerable<T>)

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I had a look at the implementation of several extension methods of the genious [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/)- project. And I came across a style habit that I cannot explain. Maybe some of you can?

It happens for example in [Pairwise.cs](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs), cited below.

So why would the author author a local function named `_()` just to call it in the return expression? Wouldn't it be straight forward just to implement the `yield return`/`yield break` in the very function? My suspicion is that it has something to do with the way the compiler generates the Enumerator-object off the yield implementation. But I don't see a difference. *Actually there is even some closure-ing happening - I regard that as even worse (!?)*
**Edit:** No, it should not be closured, because it is not a lambda but a local function which will just grab the outer scope variables whatever they are.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Pairwise<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

        return _(); IEnumerable<TResult> _()
        {
            using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext())
                    yield break;

                var previous = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return resultSelector(previous, e.Current);
                    previous = e.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *My suspicion is that it has something to do with the way the compiler generates the Enumerator-object off the yield implementation.* Yes. See [Why is a local function required when it is only called once?](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/412) and [Dissecting the local functions in C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/03/dissecting-the-local-functions-in-c-7/)

Comment: To implement IEnumerable you need to have IEnumerate() which is the MoveNext() method, and Current

Comment: Thanks, it's explained right in his issue tracking - I rather thought about code size efficiencies or code runtime efficiencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's to make argument validation eager but allow the rest of the method to be written using `yield`. With it, you get an exception relating to the arguments at the point at which you call `Pairwise<TSource, TResult>`.

Without it, you'd get the exception when you first call `MoveNext` on the returned enumerator.

Comment: side note: you often see similar things in `async` code (especially if there's a good chance of it actually being synchronous lots of the time), or in code where there is an uncommon `case` (etc) that takes more code than the rest, and you want the JIT to try and inline the common-cases (so: you want to minimize the size of the IL in the most likely scenarios, but you don't need the implementation of the awkward `case` to be available outside of that method)