# Is there value in having async in an IAsyncEnumerable function's return type?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, iasyncenumerable

We're writing extensions for `IAsyncEnumerable`. Our ultimate goal is to be able to use `System.Linq.Async`. Unfortunately, current namespace clashing precludes us from doing this. In the mean time we're writing our own and trying to conform to their signatures as much as possible to make a swap in/out as easy as possible.

We noticed a pattern and don't know why it's a thing or if it matters. Consider the two following functions.

```cs
    public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> sequence) {
        return Core(source, sequence);
        static async IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Core(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> sequence) {
            await foreach (var item in source) {
                yield return item;
            }
            await foreach (var item in sequence) {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```cs
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> ConcatAsync<TSource>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> sequence) {
        await foreach (var item in source) {
            yield return item;
        }
        await foreach (var item in sequence) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

`System.Linq.Async` uses the former in most/all of its extensions. We don't know why this is the case. Why not simply write it like the former? Ultimately, what's the difference between these two? One seems to simply wrap the other to remove the `async` from the signature. We're using C#9, for context. Which should we use and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would one define a local function in C# just to call it right away (in context of IEnumerable<T>)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54533438/11683)

Comment: not sure. digesting :)